# Permutations of a Multi-Set

Tags: combinatorics, multisets, multinomial-coefficients

Find the number of permutations of the multi-set {m.1,n.2}, where m,n $\in N $, which must contain m 1's.

I thought the permutation is $\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}$ since multi-set is basically a collection of objects with repetitions.

But the answer given is:

$\binom{m+n+1}{n}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the question specified "must have $m$ 1's", it was probably meant that upto and including $n$ 2's can be there. So you need to add together the permutations for a fixed $m$ 1's and $i$ 2's for all $0 \leq i \leq n$. For a certain $n$, you stated correctly that the number of permutations are $$\binom{m+n}{n}$$ So the total number of permutations is $$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{m+j}{j}=\binom{m+n+1}{n}$$ The last equation is an identity for binomials. Ask if you're unsure about where it came from :)

---

**Edit:**
Here's the proof for the identity at the end. We will use induction for the variable $n$:

Base case: when $n$ equals $0$, both sides are clearly equal.

Induction: Assuming the expression  holds for $n$, we have $$\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}\binom{m+j}{j}=\underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{m+j}{j}}_{\binom{m+n+1}{n}}+\binom{m+n+1}{n+1} \\=\binom{m+n+1}{n}+\binom{m+n+1}{n+1}=\binom{m+n+2}{n+1}$$ which means it holds for $n+1$ which implies it holds for all $n\geq0$. In the ending we made use of the property $$\binom{n}{k-1} + \binom{n}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k}$$ which can be proven quite easily. See [this](http://planetmath.org/pascalsruleproof).

Comment: Ah I see! I'm not sure how you get the last identity. :)

Comment: I added a proof of the identity, hopefully that'll clear it up for you.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot! =)

Comment: How did you see immediately that $\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}$ = $\binom{m+n}{n}$ ? I realized I wasn't able to see that.

Comment: I did see that, a result of a lot of exposure to it I guess. Whenever you see a factorial in the numerator and two factorials in the denominator, you learn to suspect a binomial lurking around. In this case it was relatively straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this is to first line up the m ones:  $\;\;1\;\;1\;\;1\;\cdots\;1$.

This leaves $m+1$ gaps: $\;\;\_\;1\;\;\_\;1\;\;\_\;1\;\_\cdots\_1\;\_\;1\;\_$,

so if we let $x_i$ be the number of 2's we put in gap $i$ for $1\le i\le m+1$,

we have the inequality $x_1+\cdots+x_{m+1}\le n$ $\;\;$where $x_i\ge0$ for each $i$.

If we let $x_{m+2}=n-(x_1+\cdots+x_{m+1})$,

this gives the equation $x_1+\cdots+x_{m+1}+x_{m+2}=n$, and

this equation has $\dbinom{m+1+n}{n}$ solutions in nonnegative integers.

Comment: This solution is very astonishing, and I loved it. +1!

Comment: @YellowSkies Thanks for your nice comment!